# How to Install Grsync without internet?

Tags: 12.04, grsync

I want to install Grsync on Ubuntu server 12.04 without internet,
or to download the package from Windows.

Comment: Download the latest .tar.gz and compile it. http://sourceforge.net/projects/grsync/files/

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `sudo apt-get install grsync`. It will fail, but show you the required package dependencies missing on your system. On my box, it shows:

   *The following NEW packages will be installed:
   grsync libgtk2.0-0*
2. Go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/grsync and download the missing dependencies.
3. Copy the downloaded *.deb files to `/var/cache/apt/archives/`.
4. Run `sudo apt-get install grsync` again. Now it should pick files from cache and won't require an internet connection to install `grsync`.